# Kotlin list removeAll is not working with a list

Tags: android, list, kotlin, mutable, mutablelist

Why Kotlin list removeAll doesnt not work in this example:

```
orderList.addAll(allProducts)
orderList.removeAll(allProducts)
```

The code above will add the products but not remove them. orderList is a mutableList

Product:

```
class Product : EmbeddedRealmObject {
var name: String = ""
var category: String = ""
var productDescription: String? = ""
var price: Float = 0F
var imagine: String? = null
```

}

Comment: Where does `orderList` come from?  What about `allProducts`?  You haven't given us much to work with.  (A sufficiently broken `equals` could do this, but you haven't told us what the type of the objects is, either...)

Comment: fun MeniuOfferItem(
    order: Order,
    allProducts: List<Product>,
    orderList: SnapshotStateList<Product>,
    totalPriceWithOutDelivery: MutableState<Float>
)

Comment: its inside a function

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code of `Product`.

Comment: any idea? why its not removing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you don't have proper `equals()` and `hashcode()` functions defined for your class Product. `removeAll` works by finding elements in your collection where an `equals()` equality check returns true with elements in the collection you pass to it. It also uses a Set under the hood to optimize this process, so `hashcode()` must be appropriately defined in relation to `equals()`.

You can generate `equals()` and matching `hashcode()` functions using the options in the IDE, or you can define this as a `data` class instead of a plain class. `data` classes automatically have proper `equals()` and `hashcode()` that use all the properties that are defined in the primary constructor.

Comment: It worked! I dont understand why for simple remove doesnt need equals and hashcode()

Comment: It does need them unless you are passing the same original instance, in which case `equals` would return true even though it ignores all the properties values.